# Need help to generate output of players Batting Average with remarks

Tags: arrays, c, math

Write a program that prints the batting average of 100 baseball players.
(inputs: Name, at_bats, hits).
If batting ave >=0.50, the remarks is "High", else "Low".
The output is in tabular form:  Batting Ave = Hits/At_bats.

```
Name    At bats    Hits    Ave     Remarks
Tore        20       10     0.5    High
Ingve       30        3     0.1    Low
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 2


int main(){
    int ab[MAX],h[MAX],c;
    float bat_ave;
    char n [MAX][31];

for (c = 0; c < MAX; c++)
{
    printf("Player name: "); //does not change the second name input
    scanf("%s", n[c]);
    printf("Input At bats: ");
    scanf("%d",&ab[c]);
    printf("Input Hits: ");
    scanf("%d",&h[c]);
}
system("cls");
printf("  Name     At bats     Hits     Average     Remarks\n");

for (c=0;c<MAX;c++){
    bat_ave = (h[c]/ab[c]); //problematic equation
    printf("%d.)  %s\t%d\t%d\t%lf\t",c+1,n,ab[c],h[c],bat_ave);
    if (bat_ave>=0.50)
        printf("High \n", n);
    else
        printf("Low \n", n);
}
return 0;
```

}

---

I get the following OUTPUT: :(

```
Player name: Red
Input At bats: 200
Input Hits: 70
Player name: Blue
Input At bats: 200
Input Hits: 150
sh: 1: cls: not found
Name     At bats     Hits     Average     Remarks
1.)Red    200         70      0.000000     Low 
2.)Red    200        150      0.000000     Low
```

Comment: As for what seems to be the question: `h[c]/ab[c]` is an *integer* division, dividing two *integers*, and yielding an *integer* result. Assigning that integer result to a floating point variable doesn't magically make the non-existing decimals appear.

Comment: Also, think about the `n` when used in the argument list for the output.

Comment: Expected output: "Ingve" under credited... 3 hits / 30 ABs = 0.1, not 0.01... Coding is being careful about seemingly insignificant details. That's were the bugs live... WORD OF WARNING: floating point numbers are approximate... Some ratios may yield 0.49999999... Coder must decide if that qualifies as 0.5....

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the proper result on the mathematical equation. I changed the int to double for h[c]/ab[c].

However, the input names does not change. Still need to figure it out

Comment: @xtie83 See my second comment.

Comment: It worked!!!! I just needed to put n[c] in scanf and printf section and remove it at the succeeding printfs. Thank you so much for your valuable input. I'm saved! ;)